# Why my custom html is not displayed when jstree is populated

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, jstree

i want to have `jstree` with my custom `html` data

i want to get similar result as show below with `jstree`

```css
 ul.ascii li{position: relative;}
```

```html
<div class="container">

    <ul class="ascii">
        <li><i class="fa fa-caret-right show-tree-children"></i><a href="#">item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item 5</a></li>
        <li>
            <ul>
    
                <li><i class="fa fa-caret-right show-tree-children"></i><a href="#">item sub 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">item sub 2</a><div style="position: absolute; left: 257px; top: 0;">Hello world 1</div></li>
                <li><a href="#">item sub 3</a> </li>
                <li>
                    <ul>
            
                        <li><i class="fa fa-caret-right show-tree-children"></i><a href="#">item sub sub 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">item sub sub 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">item sub sub 3</a> <div style="position: absolute; left: 257px; top: 0;">Hello world 1</div></li>
                        <li>
                            <ul>
                                <li><i class="fa fa-caret-right show-tree-children"></i><a href="#">item sub sub sub 1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">item sub sub sub 2</a></li>
                                <li style="position:relative;"><a href="#">item sub sub sub 3</a> <div style="position: absolute; left: 257px; top: 0;">Hello world 3</div></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**Question:** i want to achieve similar result as above (code snippet).

retaining  ,"hello world 1" .. "hello world 3"

**Problem i'm facing**: "hello world 1" to "hello world 3" is being removed, when **jstree** is rendered.

**below is my jstree code:**

```js
$("#jstree").jstree({ 
     "plugins" : [ "themes", "html_data" ]
});
```

```css
 ul.ascii li{position: relative;}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.2.1/themes/default/style.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.2.1/jstree.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" id="jstree">

    <ul class="ascii"> 
        <li><i class="fa fa-caret-right show-tree-children"></i><a href="#">item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item 5</a></li>
        <li>
            <ul>
    
                <li><i class="fa fa-caret-right show-tree-children"></i><a href="#">item sub 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">item sub 2</a><div style="position: absolute; left: 257px; top: 0;">Hello world 1</div></li>
                <li><a href="#">item sub 3</a> </li>
                <li>
                    <ul>
            
                        <li><i class="fa fa-caret-right show-tree-children"></i><a href="#">item sub sub 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">item sub sub 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">item sub sub 3</a> <div style="position: absolute; left: 257px; top: 0;">Hello world 1</div></li>
                        <li>
                            <ul>
                                <li><i class="fa fa-caret-right show-tree-children"></i><a href="#">item sub sub sub 1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">item sub sub sub 2</a></li>
                                <li style="position:relative;"><a href="#">item sub sub sub 3</a> <div style="position: absolute; left: 257px; top: 0;">Hello world</div></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**Edit 1:**

**input is not clickable**

```js
$("#jstree").jstree({ 
     "plugins" : [ "themes", "html_data" ]
});
```

```css
ul.ascii li{position: relative;}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.2.1/themes/default/style.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.2.1/jstree.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" id="jstree">

    <ul class="ascii"> 
        <li><i class="fa fa-caret-right show-tree-children"></i><a href="#">item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item 5</a></li>
        <li>
            <ul>
    
                <li><i class="fa fa-caret-right show-tree-children"></i><a href="#">item sub 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">item sub 2 <span style="position: absolute; left: 257px;"><input type="input"/></span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#">item sub 3</a> </li>
                <li>
                    <ul>
            
                        <li><i class="fa fa-caret-right show-tree-children"></i><a href="#">item sub sub 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">item sub sub 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">item sub sub 3 <span style="position: absolute; left: 257px; "><input type="input"/></span></a> </li>
                        <li>
                            <ul>
                                <li><i class="fa fa-caret-right show-tree-children"></i><a href="#">item sub sub sub 1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">item sub sub sub 2</a></li>
                                <li style="position:relative;"><a href="#">item sub sub sub 3 <span style="position: absolute; left: 257px;"><input type="input"/></span></a> </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Please help me thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is put your custom HTML into a tag of li.

```js
$(function(){
$("#jstree").jstree({ 
     "plugins" : [ "themes", "html_data" ]
});

});
$(document).on('click','#jstree a input',function(e){
 event.preventDefault(e);
 $(this).focus();
});
```

```css
ul.ascii li{position: relative;}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.2.1/themes/default/style.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.2.1/jstree.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" id="jstree">

    <ul class="ascii"> 
        <li><i class="fa fa-caret-right show-tree-children"></i><a href="#">item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item 5</a></li>
        <li>
            <ul>
    
                <li><i class="fa fa-caret-right show-tree-children"></i><a href="#">item sub 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">item sub 2 <span style="position: absolute; left: 257px;"><input type="input"/></span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#">item sub 3</a> </li>
                <li>
                    <ul>
            
                        <li><i class="fa fa-caret-right show-tree-children"></i><a href="#">item sub sub 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">item sub sub 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">item sub sub 3 <span style="position: absolute; left: 257px; "><input type="input"/></span></a> </li>
                        <li>
                            <ul>
                                <li><i class="fa fa-caret-right show-tree-children"></i><a href="#">item sub sub sub 1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">item sub sub sub 2</a></li>
                                <li style="position:relative;"><a href="#">item sub sub sub 3 <span style="position: absolute; left: 257px;"><input type="input"/></span></a> </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Definitely, i will accept your solution, but please have a look on **Edit 1** where input is not clickable. please help me thanks in advance!!!

Comment: are you there? got any solution?

Comment: Yes, I have edited my answer and input is now clickable.Please check and mark answer as right.